# How to replace Hydrogen atom with another atom using RDKit?

Tags: replace, rdkit

Assume that I have a molecule as below.

```
smile = 'C(CN)SS'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smile)
```

[image]

As can be seen, N has two Hydrogen atoms and S has one Hydrogen atom. I would like to replace those Hydrogens with Carbon.

I can find neighbor atoms by the following code. But, it only returns non-Hydrogen atoms. And, I don't know how to replace Hydrogen with Carbon.

```
for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
    if atom.GetAtomicNum() != 6 and atom.GetTotalNumHs() > 0: 
        print("Neighbors", [x.GetAtomicNum() for x in atom.GetNeighbors()])
```

If you have any idea, I really appreciate it to guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you cannot see the hydrogens as Atom objects is because here these hydrogens are modelled as *implicit* hydrogens. The difference between *implicit* and *explicit* hydrogens is summarised nicely in [this article](https://nextmovesoftware.com/blog/2013/02/27/explicit-and-implicit-hydrogens-taking-liberties-with-valence/). This can also be seen using rdkit:

```py
smiles = 'C(CN)SS'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)

for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
    if atom.GetAtomicNum() != 6 and atom.GetTotalNumHs() > 0:
        element = atom.GetSymbol()
        implicit = atom.GetNumImplicitHs()
        explicit = atom.GetNumExplicitHs()
        print(element, 'Implicit:', implicit, 'Explicit:', explicit)

>>> N Implicit: 2 Explicit: 0 
>>> S Implicit: 1 Explicit: 0
```

You can set atoms as explicit easily:

```py
mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
```

The easiest way to change substructure is to use the function `Chem.ReplaceSubstructs`:

```py
match = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[NH2]')
repl = Chem.MolFromSmarts('N(-C)-C')
new_mol = Chem.ReplaceSubstructs(mol, match, repl)
```

Okay considering you want to change any hydrogen connected to a non-carbon atom into a carbon you could do something like this:

```py
smiles = 'C(CN)SS'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)

edit = Chem.RWMol(mol)
for atom in edit.GetAtoms():
    if atom.GetAtomicNum() != 6:
        for nbr in atom.GetNeighbors():
            if nbr.GetAtomicNum() == 1:
                nbr.SetAtomicNum(6)

Chem.SanitizeMol(edit)
mol = Chem.RemoveHs(edit)  # Also converts back to standard Mol
```

Comment: Thank you. "Chem.ReplaceSubstructs" requires me to define "match" & "repl" for any non-Carbon atoms. I was looking for a method to do replace H with C automatically for any non-Carbon atom.

Comment: Is there any way to show new chemical bonds with a different color? (I mean bonds between N & C, and N & S)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with `ReplaceSubstructs()`.

```
from rdkit import Chem

repl = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C')

patt = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[#1;$([#1][!#6])]')      # hydrogen not on carbon
#patt = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[#1;$([#1][#7,#16])]')   # hydrogen on nitrogen or sulfur

mol = Chem.AddHs(Chem.MolFromSmiles('C(CN)SS'))

rms = Chem.ReplaceSubstructs(mol, patt, repl, replaceAll=True)

newMol = Chem.RemoveHs(rms[0])
```